# Converting P12 to JKS Certificate Adode AIR to Native Android Issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, air, code-signing-certificate

I have an app in the play store which I built in Adbobe AIR and I'm now looking to upgrade it with a version built in native Android via Android Studio.

When it comes to certificate signing I have some issues...
When originally exporting the APK from flashbuilder I generated a self signed certificate as a .p12 file and it asked for a password for this when you first generate the certificate and then use it each time. That worked fine...

Now when creating the new native java app Android Studio obviously requires .jks to sign with.

I have apparently successfully converted the old .p12 to jks using the keytool in java using the technique highlighted here in one of the comments:
http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

When I attempt to Generate Signed APK for the app from Android Studio it prompts for:

- "Key store path" - Ive got that
- "Key store password" - got that.
- "Key alias" - How do I find this out??
- "Key password" - Where was this set originally??

So basically I'm stuck not knowing what the key alias and key password is because these things are never asked for when the .p12 was created in FlashBuilder originally.

Any help around how to accomplish this conversion would be appreciated.

Thanks Marco

Answer (score 2):

Ok I worked this out for anyone wondering what the deal with converting p12 to jks.
When I converted my old p12 certificate I used the inbfo on this page:
http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

I used the following command(with my own file names):
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore alice.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore alice.jks .

This creates a default alias in the new keystore called "1" and the password for that actual key is the same password that was originally used in flashbuilder to create the old p12 certificate.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my problem too moving from Adobe Air.